# com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, cucumber, bdd

I am getting the error : com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=serveraddress:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}

In a mongo cluster , there are three nodes one primary and two secondary nodes . While running BDD test cases , initialiy the mongodb is connected . However , after 15 mins, MongoTimeOutException occurs while trying to connect with all three nodes in the cluster .

Tried to set,

```
 MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyToClusterSettings(builder ->
                builder
                    .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(dbPath))
            )
            .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder ->
                builder
                    .maxConnectionIdleTime(MAX_CONNECTION_IDLE_TIME, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .maxWaitTime(MAX_WAIT_TIME, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .minSize(MIN_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOST)
                    .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(dbPath))
            )
            .applyToSocketSettings(builder ->
                builder
                    .connectTimeout((int) CONNECT_TIMEOUT.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .readTimeout((int) READ_TIMEOUT.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(dbPath))
            )
            .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(dbPath))
            .build();
```

The variables settings are ,

```
long MAX_CONNECTION_IDLE_TIME = 60000; // 60 seconds
long MAX_WAIT_TIME = 10000; // 10 seconds
int MIN_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOST = 5;
Duration CONNECT_TIMEOUT = Duration.of(60, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
Duration READ_TIMEOUT = Duration.of(60, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
```

But this doesn't solve the problem.

Any insights to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned issue is not because of connection pool issues and related to resource configuration in Azure. While running in pipeline , the public DB link with Self hosted agent has some issues. There is private link of Mongo DB and connected to it while running in pipeline solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

mongodb run by docker container, while using spring boot to connect mongodb, there's timeout exception

```
MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017")`
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69958533/4573839), connect docker container need more setting e.g. network name,

set `-p 27017:27017` helps from [the tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/docker#how-to-use-mongodb-with-docker)

> If you need to access the MongoDB server from another application running locally, you will need to expose a port using the -p argument.

```
docker run --name mongodb -d -p 27017:27017 mongodb/mongodb-community-server:$MONGODB_VERSION
```

Install [MongoDB Community Server](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community) is more useful, click `Select package` to select platform, after installed it could connect by `localhost:27017`, besides it install [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/) which is useful to visually explore your data.